# Barbuttonitem color changes in ios6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm creating an iOS application for iOS 6.1

Application has a `UINavigationBar` and `UIToolbar` with `UIBarButtonItem`s on each screen.
The `UINavigationBar`'s `UIBarButtonItem` icons take the given custom image colour but the `UIToolbar`'s `UIBarButtonItem` icons are converting to white colour.

How do I change the `UIToolbar`'s `UIBarButtonItem` icon colour from white to  a custom image colour with out creating `UIButton`?

[image]

Comment: you should use tint color property of toolbar to change color in io6

Comment: Thanks for your response Sunny.But my Question is on Barbutton icon color it showing white color defaulty change barbuttonitem color to my custom image color

Comment: If you put image it will easy to undrstand for us, n you just put link becz of low rep.

Comment: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=d00d3b6

Comment: Viruss mca just posted my link have a look

Comment: what are you expecting? post a photo of that as well

Comment: Please look at this link   http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=d00d3b6